# Function to restart quiz

Tags: javascript, html

Need a fix for my code that allows the user to restart the quiz, hiding the previous result and restating the answer data. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Daryl13/p047yx91/11/.

As it stands the previous result is still viable as the quiz results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function endQuiz() {
    console.log("Scores were ", answerData);
    document.getElementById("question").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("quiz-img").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
    // Sort the scores in descending order and check the top 2 character types
    const sortedScores = Object.entries(answerData).sort((type1, type2) => type2[1] - type1[1]);
    myTypes = [sortedScores[0][0]];
    if (sortedScores[1][1] === sortedScores[0][1]) myTypes.push(sortedScores[1][0]);
    let result = '';
    if (myTypes.length === 1) result = "You are a " + myTypes[0];
    else result = "You could either be a " + myTypes.join(" or a ");
    document.querySelector("#result .result-text").innerHTML = result;
    document.querySelector(".result-image").innerHTML=''; 
    myTypes.forEach(t => {
    let src='';
    if (t === "warlock")  src = 'warlock.jpg';
    else if (t === "titan") src = 'titan.jpg';
    else if (t === "hunter") src = 'hunter.jpg';
    if (src) document.querySelector(".result-image").innerHTML += `<img src="assets/images/pages/${t}3.png" />`;
  });
    restart();
  }

  function restart() {
      beginQuiz.innerText = "Restart";
      document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
      currentQuestion = 0;
      answerData = {
        Warlock: 0,
        Hunter: 0,
        Titan: 0
      };
      updateQuestion()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the same button for restarting as beginning the quiz you can clear the results in the beginQuiz function like below, you'll also have to add an id to the Quiz Results header to target and clear, then set the header again when you show the results:

index.html

```html
<h2 id="result-header">Quiz Results</h2>
```

script.js

```
function startQuiz() {
  document.querySelector('#result .result-text').innerHTML = ''; // here
  document.querySelector('.result-image').innerHTML = ''; // here
  document.getElementById('result-header').innerHTML = ''; // here
  document.getElementById('intro').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('question').style.display = 'block';
  shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  currentQuestion = 0;
  choiceButtonsHandler();
  updateQuestion();
}

function endQuiz() {
  console.log('Scores were ', answerData);
  document.getElementById('question').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('quiz-img').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'block';
  // Sort the scores in descending order and check the top 2 character types
  const sortedScores = Object.entries(answerData).sort(
    (type1, type2) => type2[1] - type1[1],
  );
  myTypes = [sortedScores[0][0]];
  if (sortedScores[1][1] === sortedScores[0][1])
    myTypes.push(sortedScores[1][0]);
  let result = '';
  if (myTypes.length === 1) result = 'You are a ' + myTypes[0];
  else result = 'You could either be a ' + myTypes.join(' or a ');
  document.querySelector('#result .result-text').innerHTML = result;
  document.getElementById('result-header').innerHTML = 'Quiz Results'; // here
  document.querySelector('.result-image').innerHTML = '';
  myTypes.forEach((t) => {
    let src = '';
    if (t === 'warlock') src = 'warlock.jpg';
    else if (t === 'titan') src = 'titan.jpg';
    else if (t === 'hunter') src = 'hunter.jpg';
    if (src)
      document.querySelector(
        '.result-image',
      ).innerHTML += `<img src="assets/images/pages/${t}3.png" />`;
  });
  restart();
}
```

And only call `restart()` on a click to the Restart button not in your `endQuiz()` function

Update:
Ah I see your answer data and overwrites are referencing two different things:

```js
const answerData = { // can use const here since object properties are mutable
  // one object, with names as keys, scores as values
  warlock: 0,
  hunter: 0,
  titan: 0,
};

function restart() {
  beginQuiz.innerText = 'Restart';
  document.getElementById('intro').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'block';
  currentQuestion = 0;
  answerData = { // casing must match in order to overwrite
    warlock: 0,
    hunter: 0,
    titan: 0,
  };
  updateQuestion();
}
```

Comment: should it be an event listener link so document.getElementById("beginQuiz").addEventListener("click", restart);?

Comment: Sorry read through your code more please see above

Comment: got it real close based on your comment, unfortunately once its reset the data-set  doesn't record properly. Thanks for trying

Comment: changed the answer data to var and it did the trick! Good stuff man, cheers for the help